# UIPopoverController With NavigationController ,CGSize changes to Default When pushes a new view

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

i have UIPopoverController `initWithContentViewController:navigationController` and `setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 250)` i `presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem` and when it pushes a new `UITableViewController` view , UIPopoverController changes to default Size What is The Problem Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 250) value for each view controller that you are pushing from your navigation controller